# How to optimise proxy authentication via selenium-webdriver?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, http-proxy, squid

I've been using `selenium-webdriver` npm package for navigating to a page via a protected `squid` proxy (sanitised here):

```js
'use strict';

const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    proxy = require('selenium-webdriver/proxy'),
    proxyAddr = '<IP:PORT>',
    chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

(async () => {
    try {
        const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options(),
            driverProxyConfig = proxy.manual({
                http: proxyAddr,
                https: proxyAddr,
                bypass: ['accounts.google.com']
            });
        chromeOptions.setProxy(driverProxyConfig);
        const driver = await new Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
            .build(),
            pageCdpConnection = await driver.createCDPConnection('page');
        await driver.register('<username>', '<password>', pageCdpConnection);
        await driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/');
        await driver.sleep(10_000);
        await driver.quit();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

The example is based on a snippet in [official docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/#register-basic-auth).

###### Software versions used

- Node.js: 14.21.1 (need to stick to v14)
- Chromedriver: 111.0.5563.6
- Chrome: 111.0.5563.64
- `selenium-webdriver`: 4.8.1
- Mac OS 13.2 (Ventura), M2

When running a script like this (with correct proxy address and credential values) and looking at `squid` access logs, in the beginning of a session, I always see at least **two consecutive unauthenticated requests** (in this case, to `www.selenium.dev`) like the following (sanitised):

```
2023-03-20 10:59:51,580      0 <client-ip> TCP_DENIED/407 4284 CONNECT www.selenium.dev:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
2023-03-20 10:59:51,584      0 <client-ip> TCP_DENIED/407 4284 CONNECT www.selenium.dev:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
2023-03-20 10:59:51,954      1 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 39 CONNECT cdn.jsdelivr.net:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/146.75.121.229 -
2023-03-20 10:59:52,017     59 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 4890 CONNECT fonts.googleapis.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/142.250.186.42 -
2023-03-20 10:59:52,017     60 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 4891 CONNECT fonts.googleapis.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/142.250.186.42 -
2023-03-20 10:59:52,438    312 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 6586 CONNECT www.paypal.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/146.75.121.21 -
2023-03-20 10:59:52,750     97 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 6505 CONNECT www.paypalobjects.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/192.229.221.25 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,801  10908 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 39117 CONNECT cdn.jsdelivr.net:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/146.75.121.229 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,801  10674 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 5150 CONNECT www.netlify.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/3.74.73.235 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,808  10314 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 3455 CONNECT www.netlify.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/3.74.73.235 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,808  10860 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 9388 CONNECT fonts.googleapis.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/142.250.186.42 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,808  11188 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 572173 CONNECT www.selenium.dev:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/185.199.110.153 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,809  10683 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 6651 CONNECT plausible.io:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/169.150.247.34 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,809  10939 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 43293 CONNECT code.jquery.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/69.16.175.42 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,809  10683 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 32814 CONNECT fonts.gstatic.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/142.250.186.163 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,809  10683 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 8110 CONNECT www.paypal.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/146.75.121.21 -
2023-03-20 11:00:02,809  10161 <client-ip> TCP_TUNNEL/200 10864 CONNECT www.paypalobjects.com:443 <username> HIER_DIRECT/192.229.221.25 -
```

In my particular situation, it is crucial to see maximum **only one initial unauthenticated request** in logs. Is there a way to achieve that?